# How to make interrogative sentence with word 'Doubt'?

Tags: grammar

For example

> Do you doubt whether/that he will help you or not?

Which is the correct grammar form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **Do you doubt whether/that he will help you or not? Which is the correct grammar form?**

---

help you or not? the use of **or not is superfluous** as you have already formed the question earlier in the sentence.

"Do you doubt **whether** he will help you" means

Do you doubt **if** he will help you  ..... Do you doubt **or not**, (that) he will help you

---

Do you doubt **that** he will help you? means what it says.

---

To Answer your question both forms can be used. However the combination of **doubt and whether is preferable** in a interrogative sentence (see definition below).

**Do you doubt or not  (that) he will help you.** ....**or not** has an interrogative meaning and
can be use to ask about alternatives.

---

> **whether** conjunction (used especially in reporting questions and expressing doubts) if, or not:
>
> **Or not**
>   We can use or not in questions to ask about a range of possibilities:
>
> All references [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/not)